# Spring Mail Authentication failur

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, email

I'm trying to send email with spring boot mail api.
this is my code

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername("xxx@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("xxx");

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
```

but it does not send the email and this is the log:

```
DEBUG: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot to send mail then just configure below property.

application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=<login user to smtp server>
spring.mail.password=<login password to smtp server>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Mail sending method

```
@Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(
      String to, String subject, String text) {
        ...
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
        message.setTo(to); 
        message.setSubject(subject); 
        message.setText(text);
        emailSender.send(message);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I've used the same properties in java mode not application.properties, but the problem is that it is saying that something with the authentication fails

Comment: It is solved by itself,
the problem was something with google connection

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct and the problem was about connecting to google,
I didn't figure out why but it solved itself and now I can send email.